# Extra quotes with JSON.stringify - AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a RESTful web service that accepts either JSON or XML. The request is a large XML structure along with some values that can be entered from the screen. The XML structure should be uploaded by selecting a file. The AngularJS UI page contains the form fields along with the XML file upload option.
I am trying to convert the xml file content to JSON object and assigning to the request along with the user-filled fields.

Using the JSON.stringify method to set the POST request data which is causing extra double quotes to the json part that is retrieved from XML.

Any idea how to fix?

BR, Chandra

Answer (score 0):

> Using the JSON.stringify method to set the POST request data which is
>   causing extra double quotes to the json part that is retrieved from
>   XML.

You might want to review the object generated from the XML file content to make sure that you are getting rid of the " when you retrieve the value. For instance, for the XML

```
<parent>
    <child value="a">
</parent>
```

you want the JSON object

```
{
    child: {
        value: "a"
    }
}
```

which gives the expected

```
{"child":{"value":"a"}}
```

value when stringified.

However, if your JSON object is

```
{
    child: {
        value: '"a"'
    }
}
```

the (stringified) output string will be

```
{"child":{"value":"\"a\""}}
```

If this is what you are seeing, the fix would obviously be in your XML to javascript object parsing logic.